# MySQL 8.0: CTE WITH not execute two subclauses

Tags: mysql, percona

**Percona MySQL 8.0.15-5**

Hello everyone, could you please help  me with an issue?

I want to rewrite the query using temporary table to CTE using 'with'. This query should perform data blocking from one table to another.

The workflow is the following: we select a batch of data, insert it into the target table, then we select the maximum id from this batch, store it and while further call of procedure, the selection of data starts with this id.

'with' suits well in this case in order not to create a temporary table. I have written the following query:

```
  insert ignore quotes
  (
    time,
    symbol,
    server,
    bid,
    ask,
    last,
    volume
  )
  WITH temp AS 
  (
    SELECT
      q.id,
      q.`time`,
      q.symbol,
      q.server,
      q.bid,
      q.ask,
      q.last,
      q.volume,
      q.created_at
    FROM
      `old.quotes2` q
    WHERE
      q.id > id
    ORDER BY
      q.id asc
    LIMIT
      write_limit
  ), m AS (SELECT @max := MAX(t.id) max FROM temp t) -- m subclause not executed
  SELECT
    t.time,
    `search_or_add_of_symbol_id_from_name`(t.symbol) symbol,
    `search_of_server_id_from_name`(lower(t.server)) server,
    t.bid,
    t.ask,
    t.last,
    t.volume
  FROM temp t
```

MySQL doesn't perform the second query, called m, probably due to the fact that I don't use it in future. To solve this, I have to add an extra 'join' condition to the main 'select'.

Is it possible to force MySQL to execute 'm' subclause? Maybe there is any hint that will force the optimizer to execute the 'm' subclause?

Comment: Can't you just execute a seperate query to store the maximum id of a batch?

Comment: in this case, you need to create a temporary table
I specifically chose CTE, in order not to create a temporary table

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Option 0:

```sql
INSERT ...
WITH
  temp AS (...),
  m AS (...)
SELECT ...
FROM temp JOIN m;
```

Option 1:

```sql
INSERT ...
WITH
  temp AS (...),
  m AS (...)
SELECT ...
FROM temp, m;
```

Option 2:

```sql
INSERT ...
WITH
  temp AS (...)
SELECT ...
FROM temp, (...) m;
```